# Forward secrecy in Nginx (CentOS6)

Tags: nginx, centos6, openssl, ssl

I am trying to enable Forward secrecy in CentOS with nginx webserver.

**What I have tried**
I have read some tutorials and seems like we should have nginx, openssl latest versions to enable it. So I had installed the openssl latest from source.

```
sudo wget http://www.openssl.org/source/openssl-1.0.1e.tar.gz
sudo tar  -xvzf openssl-1.0.1e.tar.gz
cd openssl-1.0.1e
sudo ./config --prefix=/usr/local
sudo make 
sudo make install
```

Now OpenSSL supports the Eliptic Curve ciphers(ECDHE). I tested this with openssl s_server also. It worked well.

Next, I replaced Nginx with latest.

```
sudo wget  http://nginx.org/packages/centos/6/x86_64/RPMS/nginx-1.4.2-1.el6.ngx.x86_64.rpm
sudo rpm -e nginx
sudo rpm -ivh  nginx-1.4.2-1.el6.ngx.x86_64.rpm
```

and configured Nginx as described in this link

```
ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
ssl_ciphers EECDH+ECDSA+AESGCM:EECDH+aRSA+AESGCM:EECDH+ECDSA+SHA256:EECDH+aRSA+RC4:EDH+aRSA:EECDH:RC4:!aNULL:!eNULL:!LOW:!3DES:!MD5:!EXP:!PSK:!SRP:!DSS;
```

http://baudehlo.wordpress.com/2013/06/24/setting-up-perfect-forward-secrecy-for-nginx-or-stud/

But now Nginx does not support ECDHE ciphers. It supports DHE ciphers. I tried by just enabling ECDHE cipher in nginx still doesn't work. I am using latest web browser(chrome 29 and it support this cipher)

Am i missing anything ? Or Having issues with CentOS or Nginx? I read somewhere that ECC patent issues with CentOS, is this causing problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are right that ECC in RedHat's (and therefore in CentOS's) `openssl` is disabled, due to patent concerns; see (eg) [this bugzilla entry](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=319901) for more details.  Note how any time anyone opens a new tracker to compain, it's closed as a duplicate of this one, so don't be fooled by the age of the tracker into thinking that it's a lapsed problem (side note: although most of that bugzilla is bad news, I did like RH's comment '*Please note: "Ubuntu does it" is never a viable legal argument.*').

You have correctly divined that getting round that will mean compiling your own `openssl`, which is good.  But having done so, you can't simply install packaged binaries and expect them to magically pick up your new libraries, because they won't.

You'll need to recompile openssl, with eg `--prefix=/usr/local/openssl-custom`, then `make install` it to that new location, then compile `nginx` from source taking care to tell it to compile and link against the new libraries (I can't give you a standard incantation for that, because it varies from package to package, but `-with-ssl=/usr/local/openssl-custom` can sometimes be the right thing).

If you need any other tools to work with `nginx`, and any of those have `openssl` dependencies (and these days, what doesn't?), you will likely need to compile those, also.

Please let me end by discouraging you from this.  It's a lot of work; the compilation is the least of it, you then have to stay on top of all new releases of the packages you're built, and rebuild them whenever they change.  **I don't know why you've decided you need Forward Secrecy, but I strongly suspect that you will cause yourself more security issues by packages getting out-of-patch than you will ever fix by enabling it.**

Note also comments 43 and 90 in the bugzilla entry linked above; if by Forward Secrecy, you mean Perfect Forward Secrecy (PFS), then enabling PFS does **not** seem to require having ECC.  Or just wait, since [it looks like we're getting ECC as of RHEL6.5 (C6.5)](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=960193).

Comment: To avoid RSA key compromising vulnerabilities is the reason to enable PFS, I am using AWS Beanstalk Environment that's why stick to CentOS. I will try to compile Nginx as you told above. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

as a tl;dr for what MadHatter suggested:

there is an option to have nginx run with modern ssl if your openssl is a little outdated:

- download and extract sources from [openssl](http://www.openssl.org/source/)
- configure nginx to use your downloaded openssl-sources:

  ```
  ./configure ... --with-openssl=/path/to/openssl_source/ ...
  ```
- build your packages

then you'll have an updated nginx with modern ssl, build statically and w/out interfering with your openssl-package from your distribution.

for more infos on nginx + ssl see this [guide to nginx and ssl](http://www.mare-system.de/guide-to-nginx-ssl-spdy-hsts/#workaround-for-outdated-openssl-versions)

Comment: @MadHatter: corrected :)

Answer (score 0):

I use

```
yum --enablerepo=axivo install nginx
```

and

```
yum --enablerepo=axivo update openssl
```

Instructions for Nginx [here](https://www.axivo.com/resources/basic-configuration.3/) and for OpenSSL [here](https://www.axivo.com/resources/openssl-setup.2/).

This installs (at the time of this answer) Nginx 1.4.4 and OpenSSL 1.0.1e

Apache (httpd) gave me problems and I had to recompile but other then that everything is fine with this setup.

I've also spent a long time kinda perfecting this cipher preference (for me) --  inspired by Google:

```
ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-RC4-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:AES128-GCM-SHA256:RC4-SHA:RC4-MD5:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES256-SHA256:AES256-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:AES128-SHA256:AES128-SHA;
```

Use it at your own risk.

You can use ssllabs.com to test.

Comment: Why are you using a third party OpenSSL package? This should no longer be necessary with EL 6.5.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Because it's a crippled version that's not optimized. See [this](https://www.axivo.com/resources/openssl-setup.2/updates).